# Finding length of a document using python docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I am trying to a loop from the first to last line of a word document. I am using python-docx package.
Documents deals with paragraphs & tables as well. 
What I want to do is: Write a for loop from first to last of the document and do something for paragraphs & tables

How do I iterate through each line in python?

Comment: What is a line? Documents deal with paragraphs, not lines.

Comment: Yes. Documents deals with paragraphs & tables as well. What I want to do is: Write a for loop from first to last of the document and do something for paragraphs & tables.

Comment: Would you mind asking that in your question?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/40

Answer (score 0):

Pass the filepath to the following function:

```
import docx

def getText(filepath):
    doc = docx.Document(filepath)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)
```

it will return you a list of lines. (Lines here might be different than the line you see in the document)

then you can iterate using:

```
for paragraph in getText(filepath).split('\n'):
    # do what you will with the line
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would help:

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document('your file')
for i in doc.paragraphs:
     do something
```